# How to access the JSON field in Fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fullcalendar

I am developing a Appointment tool in PHP/jQuery. I am getting all the appointments as a JSON object like below :

```
[
  {
    "title": "Appointment with Zach Green{3}",
    "appointment_id": "3",
    "start": "2019-01-30T10:30:00",
    "end": "2019-01-30T11:45:00",
    "backgroundColor": "#226fbe",
    "borderColor": "#226fbe"
  },
  {
    "title": "Appointment with Mark Sammons{4}",
    "appointment_id": "4",
    "start": "2019-01-29T11:30:00",
    "end": "2019-01-29T12:45:00",
    "backgroundColor": "#226fbe",
    "borderColor": "#226fbe"
  }
]
```

Currently, I am passing `appointment_id` by appending to the title and parsing the id in jQuery. However, the `appointment_id` is displayed on the calendar which I would like to avoid.

Attached is the screenshot of the calendar

[image]

[image]

Any idea how to do it ?

Comment: You haven't shown us any code so it is hard to guess what you're trying to do and in what context. Are you trying to access the ID when clicking on events?  `eventClick` has access to all your event properties [in the `event` parameter](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick).  I'm wild guessing but we have nothing to go on :-)

Comment: I am sorry, Its my mistake. I notice that 'event' object has all the elements of the JSON object. I could access it directly like `event.appointment_id`. Really appreciate your feedback and help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing with the title you can set up a custom attribute and get it from the event.

eg:

```
<input type="hidden" data-id="yourid here" class="appoimentId">

$('.appoimentId').click(function(){
   //id on each item click
   console.log($(this).attr('data-id'));
})
```

Comment: it's unclear how this hidden field relates in any way to a fullCalendar event??

Answer (score 0):

While fullCalendar [specifies](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) the properties for an event which it recognises and will affect the calendar functionality in various ways, there's nothing to stop you adding custom properties for your event in the JSON in the way you have done.

Anytime in the event's lifecycle where you can get access the raw `event` object which fullCalendar is storing, then you have access to your custom data as well.

You haven't said exactly what you want to do with the Appointment ID, but for example if you wanted to use it for some purpose when someone clicks on the event, then the [eventClick](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick) callback gives you a way to access the properties of the clicked event.

So as a very simple example you should be able to write:

```
eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view)
{
  alert("Appointment ID:" + event.appointment_id);
}
```

And this will show the alert box whenever the user clicks your event.